# How to get all commits that originated in a branch, from the GitLab API?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I am currently using the API to get all of the commits from the master branch like this:

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${projectID}/repository/commits?ref=master&per_page=50&page=1
```

This works well except it's returning commits which didn't originate in the master branch, and then were committed to the master branch.

If I use the graph view in GitLab, this becomes quite clear: [GraphView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8zXa.png)

It helps illustrate what I am interested in polling. Red is the master branch, and the green paths coming off of it were other various branches I created and merged back in. I want to receive a response with each of the commits that are red dots in this image I attached. I don't care for the green dots, or any other dot that was originating from outside of the master branch.

If anyone can help me understand how I can either:

- Get a list of commits similar to what I'd described above using the GitLab API
- Filter the commits from the `repository/commits` request to only show the ones which originated in the master branch, using the GitLab API

I would very much appreciate it! Thank you,

David

I tried adding `?ref=master` to the API request to filter to the master branch, but it shows the parent commits of merged branches as being in master. This is fine, I get that this is probably the expected behaviour. I am just looking for a solution,